# Python: use the same function both as standalone and as a decorator

Tags: python

So I have two functions, `init` that defines a vector, and `normalise` that normalises it.

I also have `init2`and `normalise2` that are set up such that `normalise2` is a decorator for `init2`.

```
import numpy as np

def normalise(vec):
    return vec/np.sum(vec)

def init(size):
    vec = np.ones(size)
    return vec

def normalise2(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return func(*args)/np.sum(*args)
    return wrapper

@normalise2
def init2(size):
    vec = np.ones(size)
    return vec
```

So if I say `a = init2(3)` I get a normalised 3-long vector `array([0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333])`.

But if I already have a vector `c = np.array([5,2,7])` and I want to normalise it, I have to do:

`d = normalise(c)`

i.e. I have to use the non-decorator version of `normalise`.

Is there a way to define the function `normalise` so that I can use it both as a standalone function and as a decorator?

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a generic and maintainable setup by using [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to make a [single dispatch generic function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-single-dispatch) that will chose its implementation based on the argument. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def normalise(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return func(*args)/np.sum(*args)
    return wrapper

# when passed an ndarray or list:
@normalise.register(list)
@normalise.register(np.ndarray)
def _(vec):
    return vec/np.sum(vec)

@normalise
def init(size):
    vec = np.ones(size)
    return vec


c = np.array([5,2,7])
init(3), normalise(c), normalise([5, 2, 7)

# (array([0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333]),
#  array([0.35714286, 0.14285714, 0.5       ]),
#  array([0.35714286, 0.14285714, 0.5       ]))
```

Comment: What exactly does the `.register` do? I can't easily find it in decorators' documentations.

Comment: @SuperCiocia `register()` adds overloaded implementations to the function based on the typing — either of the type passed in or of the typing of the function if you annoyed the argument with a typing.

Answer (score 1):

You can always have the implementation magically do different things depending on the type of the argument(s):

```
def normalise(arg):
    if not callable(arg):
        return vec/np.sum(arg)
    else:
        return lambda vec: normalise(arg(vec))
```

Personally, I would not recommend doing this.  Beware the magic!  :)

Comment: And why would you advise against doing it?

Comment: Generally functions that have radically different behaviors/signatures depending on context are difficult to reason about (and difficult to typecheck, although you can make it work with careful use of `@overload`).  There's no good reason to not just give them different names to reflect their different usage IMO.